# Scraping nested items with Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tiktok

How can I access the content inside the highlighted class (image bellow)? I am trying to print all comments from a TikTok video ([url here](https://www.tiktok.com/@adhdvision/video/7156974534078385413?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7156974534078385413)), but I haven't manage to do it. I have tried several different approaches (listed bellow), but they always retrieved empty variables. I tested:

With bs4:

```
url_ = urllib.request.urlopen(url)  
content = url_.read()  
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
# 1.
containers = soup.find_all('p',{'data-e2e':'comment-level-1'})
# or 2. (to access the container and then somehow access the sub-container)
containers = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"content-tiktok-1mf23fd-DivContentContainer e1g2efjf1"})
```

With Selenium:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)  
browser.get(url)  
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")  
comm = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tiktok-q9aj5z-PCommentText e1g2efjf6")
```

I managed to make it work with Selenium using Xpath, but this thing changes among container to container, so it does not work because a have a lot of this "boxes".

This works with Selenium for only one comment box:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)  
browser.get(url)  
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="7156976296152449797"]/div[1]/p[1]')
print(element.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'll point you to some issues you have within the code, your trying to find an element by it's xpath that's always changing, thus the Simpler way is to find some class name thats 'static' so you can loop through it and get all comments!!

```
#change this  
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="7156976296152449797"]/div[1]/p[1]')

#to this => and notice the element(s) not element
element  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "DivContentContainer")]/p[1]')

for elem in element:
    print(elem.text)
```

- Nt : I Tested the code and it's retrieving all the comments you set the scrollHeight to !!!. Thus, to get Further comments include `time.sleep() or  WebDriverWait()` before scrolling bellow to get more Comments.
- The 'Replies' are not included, Since you have to check if every comment has replies, if no skip every time.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to target the part of the class that does not change - the `CommentContent`, and `CommentText` parts.

In bs4, `select` with [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) is great for targeting nested tags, or tags by partial attributes:

```py
containers = soup.select('div[class*="CommentContent"]') # comment content
commentItems = soup.select('div[class*="CommentItem"]') # outermost comment containers
commentTexts = soup.select('div[class*="CommentContent"] p[class*="CommentText"]') # same as find_all('p',{'data-e2e':'comment-level-1'})
commenterNames = soup.select('div[class*="CommentContent"] span[class*="UserName"]') # usernames of commenters
```

The same elements can be targeted with selenium and [xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath)

```py
containers = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "CommentContent")]')  
commentItems = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "CommentItem")]') 
commentTexts = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "CommentContent")]//p[contains(@class, "CommentText")]') 
commenterNames = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "CommentContent")]//span[contains(@class, "UserName")]')
```